# Cooking with flatscreens

Tags: environment, post-apocalypse

If you were stuck in a dystopian future, where all technology was useless but still littered around (and so physically available), what would you re-purpose to enable you to cook a stew? Fire surround, stew pot, stirrer, what to burn etc etc

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence at all. I also don't see how the title and body match, but I get that one might want to utilize the click-bait potential to the fullest. Please note that cooking a stew is not a technological issue. All people, even the so-called lost tribes or our distant ancestors from 2 million years ago, know how to make fire and cook their food. You don't need to enable this with old technology.

Comment: Do you mean that all the normal stuff one could use to cook a stew (vegetables, wood, cooking pots etc) has been taken, and all you are left with is computer equipment?

Comment: in just five minutes I came up with several different solutions, from old fashioned to latest trends. Unless you better specify the type of technologies this is too broad.

Comment: Just as you say, Max. All that's left is computer equipment to enable the physical act of cooking a stew.

Comment: This question needs a lot more clarification of the exact constraints. Are there still fibrous office furnishings? Books? Plants? Animals? Working Electricity? This is far too broad to answer currently - without resorting to "pick up *flammable material* -> make campfire -> cook food".

Comment: Plastic burns. It might release carcinogens, but when you've got nothing else and you MUST have fire, it works. Though, I'm surprised you can't get wood to burn. That gives rise to a lot of new questions.

Comment: You can cook stew using a number of working computer's components, but flatscreen isn't one of them.

Comment: @TomDussek: Please take some time to expand on the scenario: "Only computer equipment" - is not going to make a stew. You need vegetables for that - so there would be vegetation? Or are they from tins - in which case you would not need cooking? Why is there nothing but computer equipment? No kitchens? No cars? No fossil fuel? No solar cells? No tool sheds?